# Why does my UI5 FileUploader not react to changed property values?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I have a UI5-FileUploader.

```xml
<u:FileUploader
id="fileUploader"
uploadUrl="upload/" width="100%" uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" typeMissmatch="handleTypeMissmatch style="Emphasized" fileType="{view>/uploadType}"/>
```

The `ViewModel` contains this entry:

```js
const modelData = {uploadType: "xlsx"}
```

The document search blends out any document not matching the type of 'Microsoft Excel Worksheet (*.xlsx)' [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pYEm.png)

However, I want the radio-buttons trigger to change the `fileType` to `csv` and back.
Usually this is achieved by either changing the model value

```js
oModel.setProperty("/uploadType", "csv"); 
oModel.refresh(true);
```

or, if no binding is defined direct

```js
this.getView().byId("fileUploader").setFileType("csv");
```

While in both cases the `fileType` property updates correctly, has a valid value and no errors are shown, the document search window remains the same and still searches for '*.xlsx' documents. Why does this happen?

Comment: why would you like to annoy the user with a filetype switch. Can you just enable both?

Comment: FYI: ```oModel.refresh(true);```is not needed. UI5 is doing this for you. Check out two way binding: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected in the current ui5 version, chrome on OSX.

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {

  onInit: function(oEvent) {
    this._oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        uploadType: "xlsx"
     });
    this.getView().setModel( this._oModel);
  },

  onSelect: function(oEvent) {
    if (this._oModel.getProperty("/uploadType") === 'pdf') {
       this._oModel.setProperty("/uploadType", "xlsx");
    } else {
      this._oModel.setProperty("/uploadType", "pdf");
    }
  }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
  viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
}).placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified">
    <Text text="{/uploadType}" />
    <RadioButtonGroup select="onSelect">
      <RadioButton text="xlsx" selected="true" />
      <RadioButton text="pdf" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
    <u:FileUploader id="fileUploader" name="myFileUpload" uploadUrl="upload/" fileType="{/uploadType}" />
  </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot.

Ive copied this snippet 1:1 to my project, replacing my existing elements and functions and it does not work.

Interestingly, it does work in an older git-branch.

Do you know what could be interfering? It does not seem to be a browser problem either.

Comment: whats your ui5-Version, Browser, Operating-System? How do you create your json model? You have to provide a reproducible example to solve this problem via stack-overflow

Comment: (Don't forget to ▲ Upvote answers that are helpful and to ✓＋▲ Accept and Upvote an answer that helped you solve your problem!)